# How do I get the width and height of an image?

Tags: actionscript-3, image, png, flexbuilder

I'm constructing a book of sorts in Actionscript 3 (FlexBuilder) and am trying to size an image dynamically according to the dimensions of it's source file.  But, I've found that if I don't explicitly state the width and height of an image, they trace as 0.

So that I can scale down an image to fit within a given space, how do I get the width and height of a source image?

Comment: How are you accessing the image?  Loaded via Request?

Comment: I meant, loaded via a Loader? If so, Loader is a proxy for the actual content, so Loader would have the width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do these help?

- http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?p=454729
- http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=139092
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic14727.htm

Comment: The two answers are pretty close, and the second example here looks like it might be what I need.  I have to load the image, then run the numbers with scaling for width and height, then set the image to the best fit for the available space.

Answer (score 0):

A flash.display.Loader has width and height attributes.